# How to decompress Strings in Java?

Tags: java

My professor give me the assignment to decompress Strings in Java. The assignment has the following examples:

Input1 : 2[abc]3[ab]c
Output1 : abcabcabababc

Input2 : 10[a]c2[ab]
Output2 : aaaaaaaaaacabab

Input3 : 2[3[a]b]
Output3 : aaabaaab

Can somebody help and explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a Homework problem, I will not post you the code solution but I can help you with the walk through (hint) steps to solve the above problem.

Use STACKS Data Structure. to build the business logic moreover you can refer to this problem which is called as [balanced parenthesis](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/)

in the second step build the logic for repetition of the string for that you need to iterate string as per the count of the digit.